# Matlab function quiver3 - vectors are disconnected

Tags: matlab, vector, 3d, plot

The following code draws vectors disconnected, while they are supposed to touch each other. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

```
quiver3(0,0,0,50,50,50);
text(30,30,30,' \leftarrow Views and Eq. returns','FontSize',11, 'FontWeight','bold', 'FontName', 'Palatino Linotype')
hold on
quiver3(0,0,0, 50, 50, 0);
text(30,30,0,' \leftarrow Expected returns (projection/unknows)','FontSize',11, 'FontWeight','bold', 'FontName', 'Palatino Linotype')
quiver3(50,50,0, 0, 0, 50);

grid on
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing in R2013a. Try setting the scale parameter, i.e., an optional seventh argument, equal to one:

```
figure;
quiver3(0,0,0, 50,50,50, 1);
text(30,30,30,' \leftarrow Views and Eq. returns','FontSize',11, 'FontWeight','bold', 'FontName', 'Palatino Linotype')
hold on
quiver3(0,0,0, 50,50,0, 1);
text(30,30,0,' \leftarrow Expected returns (projection/unknows)','FontSize',11, 'FontWeight','bold', 'FontName', 'Palatino Linotype')
quiver3(50,50,0, 0,0,50, 1);
grid on
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html) some for of automatic scaling may be used. No idea why the default isn't one. You can also try disabling scaling by using a scale value of zero – this might even be safer for your type of application.

Comment: Thank you, horchler! adding 1 worked. My matlab version is R2011a